# Why not a NullPointerException while accessing static with null reference?

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception

Here in following code we are getting value of `i` on a null reference, though a `NPE` is not there.

```
public class Test {
    static int i = 10;

    Test getTest() {
        return null;    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.getTest());  
        System.out.println(t.getTest().i);
    }
}
```

output

```
null
10
```

Comment: Check it here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/21037406/1686291

Comment: Since this can be a confusing scenario, it will actually generate a compiler warning in Eclipse: "Non-static access to a static member."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Java Language Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#d5e19902)

***`Receiver Variable Is Irrelevant For static Field Access`***

The following program demonstrates that a null reference may be used to access a class (static) variable without causing an exception:

```
class Test3 {
    static String mountain = "Chocorua";
    static Test3 favorite(){
        System.out.print("Mount ");
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(favorite().mountain);
    }
}
```

It compiles, executes, and prints:

```
Mount Chocorua
```

***Even though the result of favorite() is null, a NullPointerException is not thrown. That "Mount " is printed demonstrates that the Primary expression is indeed fully evaluated at run time, despite the fact that only its type, not its value, is used to determine which field to access (because the field mountain is static).***

Implies even though primary expression (Here is instance) is evaluated at run time, but its value is discarded and only its type is considered.

Answer (score 7):

Informally speaking, you can think of this

```
System.out.println(t.getTest().i);
```

as being equivalent to

```
System.out.println(Test.i);
```

because `i` is static.

This is the simplest answer probably.

Strictly speaking, they are not equivalent. Actually
`getTest()` is called but its return value is not used
for accessing the `i` field as this test below shows.

```
public class Test {
    static int i = 10;

    Test getTest() {
        System.out.println("Method getTest() called!");
        return null;    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.getTest());  
        System.out.println(t.getTest().i);
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed.. The only logical answer is that.. But the compiler should do this during compilation itself... On finding i, it should replace t.getTest() with Test. Otherwise if t.getTest() is executed, then it returns null which cannot be used to access i... correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: see my answer, the two are not equivalent, although both access i in a static way

Comment: `t.getTest()` will be executed, but the result will not be used in any way.

Answer (score 4):

i being a static variable, no instance is needed to get its value.

Comment: @downvoter : please comment...

Comment: Downvoter might have thought you did not answer on allowing to access a static variable value from a *null* object

Answer (score 4):

The generated bytecode looks like this:

```
18  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [24]
21  aload_1 [t]
22  invokevirtual experiments.Experiments.getTest() : experiments.Experiments [30]
25  pop
26  getstatic experiments.Experiments.i : int [10]
29  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(int) : void [38]
```

As you see, `t.getTest()` is indeed called (21,22), but its result not used (25). The field `i` is accessed in a static way (26). Java Bytecode has no way of accessing static members via an instance. Note that this means that `t.getTest().i` and `Test.i` are *not* equivalent expressions! In a hypothetical syntax, the equivalent could look like this (using the semantics I'd find intuitive for this syntax:

```
System.out.println( {t.getTest(); return Test.i;} );
```

Note that the same holds for a field `test`: `t.test.i` is different from `Test.i`. Although getting the field can't have any side effects and is not a valid statement on its own, the field access could still be advised by AspectJ or something similar.

Comment: Are you sure that the getTest() being called is not for the first t.getTest() ?

Comment: entirely. 18 is the second `getstatic java.lang.System.out` in the bytecode, and the line numbers tell me the same. Besides that, the lines in the bytecode make perfect sense for coding the second `println`. I can clarify it if you want

Comment: No need...I trust you... :)

Comment: @SillyFreak "*Note that this means that `t.getTest().i` and `Test.i` are not equivalent expressions!*" - can you expand it? It's very interesting.

Comment: they are equivalent in value, but not in the code executed. As I stated, `t.getTest().i` does execute `t.getTest()`, while `Test.i` obviously doesn't

Comment: @SillyFreak but then how would it work? I'm not really familiar with the bytecode, however if `t.getTest().i` does execute `t.getTest()`, then it's resolved to the Test object containing `null` value. So the question remains - how `null.i` can work?

Comment: The compiler doesn't generate anything of the `null.i` sort. It recognizes that `t.getText()` is declared to return `Test`, and that `i` is static. thus, it generates a static access `Test.i` in addition to calling `t.getText()`. if it were legal, you would write `System.out.println( {t.getTest(); return Test.i;} );` as a truly equivalent statement, at least if you interpret this in the way I find intuitive.

Comment: @SillyFreak thank you for the answer. Consider this adding to your original answer, I think it's a valuable addition!

Answer (score 2):

```
 Test t = new Test(); // initialize t
```

Here `t` isn't `null` as it has been initialized. Thus, you do not get a `NullPointerException`.

In next case where you expected a `NullPointerException` since `t.getTest()` returned `null`,

```
t.getTest().i;
```

`i` is a `static` variable and you do not need to an instance to access static variables, you can just access them directly. Thus, you do not get `NullPointerException` here too.

And moreover,

```
System.out.println(i); // is an another way to access static i
```

Answer (score 1):

Static methods or variables does not need a reference to the object. You can call it even reference to the object is null.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific,

While accessing the `Static` variable, compiler will generate an [`getStatic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.getstatic) instruction corresponding to that `static` and it will be used to access that `static`. thus static are instance independent they are resolved by the field/method using just an index to the [run time constant pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) that will be later used to solve the field reference location..

For more details refer this SO answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047440/1686291

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, compiler takes statics from class def, not from an object.
That is why you can replace `t.getTest().i` with `Test.i` and it will be the same.