# Referring to static nested class object from outer class

Tags: java

I want to refer to the variable of an object of a static nested class from the outer class. Would this work?

```
public class GuiApp {
    static class book{

        static book [] book = new book[1000];
        static Boolean overdue;
        static Boolean checkedOut;
        static int bookNum;
        static String personName;
        static String dueDate;
        static int month;
        static int date;
        static int year;
        static String dateCheckedOut;
    }
}
```

and later to refer to the variable String personName of book[50] from the outer class for example

```
book.book[50].personName = "Bob";
```

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly so I want to know if this would work.

Comment: There is no inner class here. There is a static nested class. Not the same thing.

Comment: Your class name should start with Capital Case and never use same name for two thing. Consdure change name of variable book to arrBook or books .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before accessing an element of that array :

```
book.book[50].personName = "Bob";
```

You have to initialize that element :

```
book.book[50] = new GuiApp.book();
```

I would also advise against using the same name for the class and the array.

However, making all the properties of the `book` class static makes no sense, since it means that all the books would have the same values.

Comment: Oh I just took out the static keyword but now I cannot refer to the variables and book objects in the outer class. W

Comment: @noobProgrammer Well the book[] array should remain static. You should rename that variable though. It might conflict with the class name.

Comment: @Eran `book.book[50] = new GuiApp.book();` I don't think it is required?

Comment: @eatSleepCode If you don't do it, book.book[50] will remain null and `book.book[50].personName` will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: @Eran your accessing a static field which don't require object of the class to access it.

Comment: you can refer this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255684/why-not-a-nullpointerexception-while-accessing-static-with-null-reference

Comment: @eatSleepCode your sample is different, as the accesses i is static, so the access getTest().i does not need to reference the return value but access the static class member i.

Comment: @eatSleepCode `book.book[50]` is a reference of type book which contains null when the array is initialized. Even if personName stays static (which is a bad idea, as mentioned in my answer), dereferencing a null reference always leads to a NullPointerException

Comment: @Jens-PeterHaack here `static String personName;` too a static variable, so to my opinion this seems to the same case

Comment: @Eran 
`Session1.book.book[50].personName = "bob";
System.out.println("" + Session1.book.book[50].personName );` This code works fine in my case.

Comment: @eatSleepCode OK, I tested it and you were right. Accessing a static variable via an instance doesn't throw NullPointerException even if the instance is null. I guess the compiler replaces the reference with the class name, so book.book[50].personName becomes book.personName. That said, personName shouldn't be static in the first place.

Comment: So the primary problem is that the members are declared static. If they are not static it will work... and then the reference needs an initialized book object ;-)... eatSleepCode you are completely right.